# Odoo 10: show field of model "sale.order" in form view of "account.invoice"

Tags: odoo, field, relation, qweb

I usually create a new Database Structure Field by using the Debugging Mode, then `Edit FormView` and writing e.g. `<field name="x_delivery_date"/>`. Also I can show it later on the printed report like this:

```
<div name="x_delivery_date" t-if="doc.x_delivery_date">
    <strong>Delivery Date:</strong>
    <p t-field="doc.x_delivery_date"/>
</div>
```

But how do I display a field (`commitment_date`), which is available in the model (`sale.order`) in another models formview (`account.invoice`)? I guess that I have to use object relations or related field, but I don't know how. I hope somebody can help me. Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use related fields for that. You have to add two fields to `account.invoice` to do it.

```
class AccountInvoice(models.Model):
    _inherit = "account.invoice"

    order_id = fields.Many2one('sale.order', 'Related_order')
    commitment_date = fields.Date(related='order_id.commitment_date')
```

Then you can use the commitment_date fields in `account.invoice` forms. The value of the field in `sale.order` will be reflected on the form right away. But be aware that changing the value of that field will change the value of that field on the `sale.order` as well.

**EDIT**

For reports just use the field like it is a regular field of `account.invoice` (so `doc.commitment_date`)

Comment: I get an error `ProgrammingError: column account_invoice.order_id does not exist`

Comment: You should update your module after restarting your server.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to add a many2one field in account.invoice

```
class account_invoice(osv.osv):
    _inherit = "account.invoice"

    _columns = {
        'source_id':fields.many2one('sale.order','Source')
    }
```

Then inherit the _prepare_invoice function in sale_order. In this function you are going to pass the sale order id as source id to the account.invoice

```
class sale_order(osv.osv):
    _inherit = "sale.order"

  def _prepare_invoice(self, cr, uid, order, lines, context=None):
    if context is None:
        context = {}
    journal_id = self.pool['account.invoice'].default_get(cr, uid, ['journal_id'], context=context)['journal_id']
    if not journal_id:
        raise osv.except_osv(_('Error!'),
            _('Please define sales journal for this company: "%s" (id:%d).') % (order.company_id.name, order.company_id.id))
    invoice_vals = {
        'name': order.client_order_ref or '',
        'origin': order.name,
        'type': 'out_invoice',
#Sale order id as source_id
        'source_id':order.id,
        'reference': order.client_order_ref or order.name,
        'account_id': order.partner_invoice_id.property_account_receivable.id,
        'partner_id': order.partner_invoice_id.id,
        'journal_id': journal_id,
        'invoice_line': [(6, 0, lines)],
        'currency_id': order.pricelist_id.currency_id.id,
        'comment': order.note,
        'payment_term': order.payment_term and order.payment_term.id or False,
        'fiscal_position': order.fiscal_position.id or order.partner_invoice_id.property_account_position.id,
        'date_invoice': context.get('date_invoice', False),
        'company_id': order.company_id.id,
        'user_id': order.user_id and order.user_id.id or False,
        'section_id' : order.section_id.id
    }

    invoice_vals.update(self._inv_get(cr, uid, order, context=context))
    return invoice_vals
```

Add this in View file

```
<record id="invoice_form" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">account.invoice.form</field>
            <field name="model">account.invoice</field>
            <field name="inherit_id" ref="account.invoice_form"/>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <xpath expr="//field[@name='date_invoice']" position="after">
                    <field name="source_id"/>
                </xpath>
             </field>
         </record>
```

Now add this in your report file

```
<div name="x_delivery_date" t-if="doc.x_delivery_date">
    <strong>Delivery Date:</strong>
    <p t-field="doc.x_delivery_date"/>
    <p t-field="doc.source_id.commitment_date"/>
</div>
```

Comment: This is in Odoo 8.. please convert for odoo 10. this will work for sure.

Comment: Thank you, but after adding the `_columns = {...}` line into `class AccountInvoice(models.Model)` I get a 500 server error